# How to run a quick test from Android to HTTPS server?

Tags: android, https

I have an Android app that I'm testing against an https server that I don't control.  I'd like to point the app at a local webserver that I do control, and still use https.

From reading around, it seems that `javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException` will be thrown if I use a self-signed cert on my personal web server.

Am I faced with putting a `TrustManager` in my app just for this simple test?  Or is there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple way is to install the client-side cert on the Android device itself.  Then the app won't throw the indicated exception any longer.